# Indefinite integral of $\cos^2(x)/\sin^6(x)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I can't solve this integral, can anybody help me ?

$$\int\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^6x}\mathrm dx$$

I've tried with $\frac{\cos2x+1}{2}=\cos^2x$ transformations but still cannot get the result.

Comment: Start by noting the $cot^2 (x) $

Comment: HINT: use the identity $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$.

Answer (score 5):

$\displaystyle \dfrac{\cos^2x}{\sin^6 x}=\csc^4 x \cot^2 x= (\cot x+\cot^3 x)^2 \csc^2 x$

Now integrating and letting $\cot x=y$

$I=-\int (y^2+y^6+2y^4)\; dy$

Now you can proceed.

Comment: Could you resolve this integral without $cscx$ function ?

Comment: @Mikkey Actually the power of the sine in the denominator is even, so using the $csc^2$ is really the way to go.

Comment: Every possible way would lead to the same answer. Try multiplying $\sec^6 x$ up and down instead

Comment: The problem is that i'm not allowed to use $cscx$ and $sec$, only $sinx$ $cosx$ $tanx$ $cotx$

Comment: @Mikkey Every step is still true in this answer. Just replace each function with sine and cosine and you are golden

Comment: @Mikkey Don't call it cosecant: observe that $\;\csc x=\frac1{\sin x}\;$ and etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to avoid trig, here you go
$$\int\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^6x}dx$$
$$\int\frac{1-\sin^2x}{\sin^6x}dx$$
We now let $u = \sin^2(x) \implies u' = 2\sqrt{u-u^2}$
This shrinks our interval a bit since the square root actually gives the absolute value, so we need really have the above for $[0+\pi n,\pi/2+\pi n]$.
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1-u}{u^6\sqrt{u-u^2}}du$$
You can now multiply out the denominator, make a substitution to move the square root to the top, and simplify. Good luck.

Comment: I still do not know what is $sec(x)$. I'm obligated to use only $sinx$ ,$cosx$, $tanx$ and $cotx$

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you rewrote that numerator?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\cos ^2 x}{\sin ^6 x} d x & =\int \cot ^2 x \csc ^4 x d x \\
& =-\int \cot ^2 x\left(1+\cot ^2 x\right) d(\cot x) \\
& =-\frac{\cot ^3 x}{3}-\frac{\cot ^5 x}{5}+C
\end{aligned}
$$